# what is the definition of $\mathfrak{a}^n$ inductively and how to prove its an ideal.

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ideals

Let $A$ be a ring and let $\mathfrak{a}, \mathfrak{b}$ be ideals of $A.$ Prove that the following is an ideal:

$\mathfrak{a}\mathfrak{b} = \{\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_iy_i \in A \,\, | \,\, x_i \in \mathfrak{a}, y_i \in \mathfrak{b}, n \in \mathbb N\}.$

In particular, we have $\mathfrak{a}^n$ defined inductively.

I have proved that $\mathfrak{a}\mathfrak{b}$ is an ideal but I do not understand how will be the definition of $\mathfrak{a}^n$ inductively and how to prove that it is an ideal, could someone help me in this please?

Comment: It's the same principle as how you inductively define $x^n$ after having defined a multiplication for, say, elements in a ring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We start with $\mathfrak{a}^0 ≔ A$, which is an ideal of $A$.
If we have defined the ideal $\mathfrak{a}^n$ for some natural number $n$, then we set
$$
  \mathfrak{a}^{n + 1} ≔ \mathfrak{a}^n \, \mathfrak{a} \,.
$$
This is again an ideal of $A$, because both $\mathfrak{a}^n$ and $\mathfrak{a}$ are ideals of $A$.

We have the following properties for these ideals:

- $\mathfrak{a}^0 = A$ and $\mathfrak{a}^1 = \mathfrak{a}$.
- For every natural number $n$, the ideal $\mathfrak{a}^n$ is generated by all elements of the form $x_1 \dotsm x_n$ where each $x_i$ ranges through $\mathfrak{a}$.
- For every two natural numbers $n$ and $m$, we have $\mathfrak{a}^n \mathfrak{a}^m = \mathfrak{a}^{n + m}$.
- For every two natural numbers $n$ and $m$, we have $(\mathfrak{a}^n)^m = \mathfrak{a}^{nm}$.

Comment: but this is called recursive definition not inductive definition ..... right?

Comment: @MathIgnorance Yes, strictly speaking we should say ‘recursive’ instead of ‘inductive’ here. But in the case of the natural numbers, it is somewhat common to refer to definition via recursion as ‘definition by induction’. To quote from Paul Halmo’s _Naive Set Theory_:  “Induction is often used not only to prove things but also to define things. […] An application of the recursion theorem is called _definition by induction_.”

Comment: I see thank you